# Can making class name and object name same serve the mechanism of singleton

Tags: c++

In the code below I am trying to serve the purpose of `singleton` (ie. class with single object) by making the class name and object name the same.

Is there any flaw in the code below to serve the purpose of `singleton` class?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class singleton
{
    private :
        int val;

    public : 
        void set(int a)
        {
            val=a;
        }

        int display()
        {
            return val;
        }
} singleton;


int main()
{
    singleton.set(5);
    cout << "output a = " <<singleton.display()<< endl; 
    //singleton obj;//second object will not be allowed
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Static initialization fiasco. And of course all of the issues with the singleton pattern itself.

Comment: That's just a global variable with a slightly confusing name. It's a bad idea in itself, but the singleton antipattern also enforces a single instance of the class, which is an even worse idea. You'll have to try harder if you really want to make life difficult for those maintaining your code.

Comment: thanks I think i have messed up without preparation.

Comment: Oh in a previous job they decided the database was a singleton only we needed 2 of them. I invented a new type of singleton you could have more than one of...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your type is not a singleton because you can make any number of instances of it. For example,

```
auto cpy = singleton;
cpy.set(42);
assert(singleton.display() != cpy.display());

// let's make loads of copies!
std::vector<decltype(singleton)> v(100, cpy); // 100 "singletons"!
```

But worry not, you most likely don't really need a singleton anyway.